# Thread synchronization: separate data queue and event queue

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

Let's consider the classical producer-consumer problem, in which thread A puts messages on queue Q, while thread B pops them from Q. In order for thread B to pop any message from Q, it must be notified by thread A. Let's say that there exists another queue E on which thread B waits for many different events; thread A notifies B about adding a new message on queue Q by pushing event "msg_from_A" on E. This scenario makes sense if you assume that E is not polymorphic and cannot hold variable size elements (such as messages from Q and different messages generated by another thread). When B receives "msg_from_A" it looks into queue Q and pops one element. In my implementation, access to both these queues is protected by mutexes. So B does the following:

```
while (true) {
  event = wait(E)
  switch(event){
  case "msg_from_A":
    msg = pop(Q)
    do stuff with msg ...
    break
  case "other event":
    ...
  }
}
```

Whereas A does:

```
push(msg, Q)
push("msg_from_A", E)
```

So the question is: is this correct? Is it guaranteed that message msg is pushed on Q before event "msg_from_A" is pushed on E? For if these operations happen in reverse order, there is a race condition: B might wake up before any message is pushed by A on Q, resulting in an empty pop. Although I write the operations in that order, is it possible that the compiler or the CPU reorders them? Please note that queue operations such as push are implemented internally using a mutex, which is acquired before inserting the message and subsequently released once the insertion has completed.
I hope my question is clear!

Comment: Why must thread B be notified by thread A? It makes more sense to use a condition variable on queue Q so that thread B is allowed to read data when the data is available and the queue is not otherwise locked.

Comment: @JimRogers because thread B is listening for many different events, not just "msg_from_A". With a condition variable on Q thread B would block without processing other events if the queue is empty.

Comment: Not a problem if you use the Ada programming language.

Comment: "Although I write the operations in that order, is it possible that the compiler or the CPU reorders them?" - It depends on **implementation**, and without specifying library/framework it impossible to answer where an implementation allows particular reordering or not. I don't think a "useful" library would allow to reorder operations on a message queue or to reorder unlocking a mutex and locking another one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah. I'm currently using freertos on an ARM processor. I think that unlocking a mutex would generate some write memory barrier, enforcing the instructions that do the push on E to follow the instructions that do the push on Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible that the compiler or the CPU reorders them?

That's the question, Right? If that's your question, then you can prevent the "re-ordering" by correctly using mutexes to protect the two queues.

**Rule 1:** Whatever happens within a single thread must *effectively* happen in "program order." (that is to say, every thread in your program must behave *as if* its own statements were not re-ordered.)

**Rule 2:** Whatever one thread *effectively* did before it unlocks a mutex must become *effective* for a second thread by the time the second thread subsequently locks the same mutex.

If both of your queues are "thread-safe" (i.e., if each queue has its own *private* mutex, and all of the operations on the queue are protected by the mutex) then it's going to play out like this:

```
    Producer                         Consumer
    ------------------------------   ------------------------------
                                     (awaiting event from event queue)
    Lock msg queue mutex
    Push message to msg queue
    unlock msg queue mutex

    lock event queue mutex
    Push "check-msg-Q" event to
                     event queue
    Notify event queue               Wake, and attempt to...
(1) unlock event queue mutex
(2)                                  ...lock event queue mutex
                                     Remove "check-msg-Q" from event queue
                                     unlock event queue mutex
                                     lock message queue mutex
                                     remove message
                                     unlock message queue mutex
```

According to Rule 1, everything that the producer did in program order has to have *effectively* happened in that thread by the time it reaches step (1), and according to Rule 2, everything that effectively happened in the producer thread must also have effectively happened for the consumer thread by the time the consumer thread completes step (2).

---

**You might think** that if there was only *one* producer, and only *one* consumer, and if the consumer never, ever, even *looked* at the message queue except to pop *one* message for each check-msg-queue event it received,... You might think that if all of those conditions were met, your program would work even without any lock on the message queue.

And it would work, but...

...If you pulled that stunt in a big company, and if it somehow got past code review, what happens next is; requirements change, and some other programmer comes along and relaxes one of those restrictions. Maybe they add a second producer. Maybe they make the consumer check the length of the message queue. Whatever. Now the program has a race condition. And eventually—maybe not until a long time later—it will surface as a bug that could take months to find and understand. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Comment: According to rule 1, operations should *behave* as if they were executed in program order. However couldn't pushing on Q and pushing on E be considered independent and executed in reverse order? The result on the producer is the same. The side effect is for the consumer.

Comment: @Peanut, You're right. If the producer were the only thread, then several of its operations could be re-ordered, and nobody would be able to tell the difference. But unlocking the mutex at (1) creates a [_barrier_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier). By rule 2, other threads that lock the mutex _must_ be allowed to see what the producer did, _in program order,_ before it got to the barrier. The producer thread is allowed _some_ freedom to re-order things, but it is not allowed to re-order anything with respect to the barrier.

Comment: Something similar happens in the consumer thread. Step (2) also is a barrier. Anything that the consumer does in program order after step (2) must _in actual fact_ not happen until _after_ step (2).

Comment: Thank you! These comments helped me clarify the doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example program written using Ada that solves what I think your problem is.

This program uses Ada tasks, which are commonly implemented using operating system threads, and Ada protected objects which implement thread-safe buffers used to communicate between tasks.

```ada
-- This program implements a consumer which consumes messages from
-- multiple producers. Each producer communicates through a separate queue

with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;    use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO; use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

procedure Main is
   protected A_Queue is
      entry Write (Value : in Unbounded_String);
      entry Read (Value : out Unbounded_String);
   private
      Buff   : Unbounded_String;
      Is_New : Boolean := False;
   end A_Queue;

   protected body A_Queue is
      entry Write (Value : in Unbounded_String) when not Is_New is
      begin
         Buff   := Value;
         Is_New := True;
      end Write;
      entry Read (Value : out Unbounded_String) when Is_New is
      begin
         Value  := Buff;
         Is_New := False;
      end Read;
   end A_Queue;

   protected B_Queue is
      entry Write (Value : in Integer);
      entry Read (Value : out Integer);
   private
      Buff   : Integer;
      Is_New : Boolean := False;
   end B_Queue;

   protected body B_Queue is
      entry Write (Value : in Integer) when not Is_New is
      begin
         Buff   := Value;
         Is_New := True;
      end Write;
      entry Read (Value : out Integer) when Is_New is
      begin
         Value  := Buff;
         Is_New := False;
      end Read;

   end B_Queue;

   task A;

   task body A is
      Msg : Unbounded_String :=
        To_Unbounded_String ("Message from task A number");
   begin
      for Msg_Count in 1 .. 10 loop
         A_Queue.Write (Msg & Msg_Count'Image);
      end loop;
   end A;

   task B;

   task body B is
   begin
      for Num in 100 .. 115 loop
         B_Queue.Write (Num);
      end loop;
   end B;

   A_Msg   : Unbounded_String;
   B_Msg   : Integer;
   B_Count : Natural := 0;
   A_Count : Natural := 0;
begin
   -- The main task is the consumer
   while A_Count < 10 or else B_Count < 16 loop
      -- Process messages from task A
      select
         A_Queue.Read (A_Msg);
         Put_Line (A_Msg);
         A_Count := A_Count + 1;
      or
         delay 0.001;
      end select;

      select
         B_Queue.Read (B_Msg);
         Put_Line ("Task B sent number" & B_Msg'Image);
         B_Count := B_Count + 1;
      or
         delay 0.001;
      end select;
   end loop;

end Main;
```

The entries in the protected objects have conditions associated with them. If the condition evaluates to TRUE the calling task executes the entry. If the condition evaluates to FALSE the calling task is suspended in an entry queue implicitly created by the compiler. When the entry condition evaluates to TRUE and a task is suspended in the entry queue, that task is activate automatically. The entry queue is a FIFO queue by default.

The main task, in which the main procedure executes, plays the role of the consumer in this example. The main procedure loops until 10 messages from task A and 16 messages from task B have been consumed.

Each time the main procedure calls the A_Queue.Read entry it does so in a select clause. The select clause allows the call to be performed conditionally. The call is made, and in this case a 0.001 second (1 millisecond) timer is activated. If the timer expires before the entry call is executed the call is cancelled and execution continues after the end of the select statement. The same logic is used to call B_Queue.Read.

The output of this program is:

```text
Message from task A number 1
Task B sent number 100
Message from task A number 2
Task B sent number 101
Message from task A number 3
Task B sent number 102
Message from task A number 4
Task B sent number 103
Message from task A number 5
Task B sent number 104
Message from task A number 6
Task B sent number 105
Message from task A number 7
Task B sent number 106
Message from task A number 8
Task B sent number 107
Message from task A number 9
Task B sent number 108
Message from task A number 10
Task B sent number 109
Task B sent number 110
Task B sent number 111
Task B sent number 112
Task B sent number 113
Task B sent number 114
Task B sent number 115
```

Comment: Hi! I understand the need to use a delay. However, I would like the consumer to wake up only if there's an event. I don't want to waste CPU by waking up every millisecond.

Comment: You want the consumer to respond to multiple events from different threads. The consumer cannot be suspended waiting for one event and also respond to other events. The consumer must be actively "listening" for each of the events to which it must respond. The only option is to have a separate consumer for each event, allowing each consumer to suspend until its designated event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in Ada to achieve the behavioral goal you want but it involves direct communication between the producer tasks and the consumer tasks without use of an communication buffer.

The Ada language provides task entries, which are direct synchronous communication channels between tasks. Ada implements a Rendezvous behavior for tasks employing task entries. The calling task is suspended until the called task services the entry call. Similarly, if the called task arrives at the entry call first it is suspended until its entry is called.

Task entry calls can also be handled using a select statement, allowing the called task to suspend for more than one entry call and respond to the first call to any of the accepted entries.

```ada
-- Multiple producer-single consumer without buffer

with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;    use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO; use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

procedure No_Buffer is
   task Consumer is
      entry Task_A_Event (S : in Unbounded_String);
      entry Task_B_Event (I : in Integer);
   end Consumer;

   task body consumer is
      A_Msg : Unbounded_String;
      B_Msg : Integer;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept Task_A_Event (S : in Unbounded_String) do
               A_Msg := S;
            end Task_A_Event;
            Put_Line (A_Msg);
         or
            accept Task_B_Event (I : in Integer) do
               B_Msg := I;
            end Task_B_Event;
            Put_Line ("Task B sent the value" & B_Msg'Image);
         or
            terminate;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end consumer;

   task Task_A;

   task body Task_A is
      Msg : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String ("Task A message number");
   begin
      for I in 1 .. 10 loop
         Consumer.Task_A_Event (Msg & I'Image);
      end loop;
   end Task_A;

   task task_B;

   task body Task_B is
   begin
      for I in 100 .. 115 loop
         Consumer.Task_B_Event (I);
      end loop;
   end Task_B;

begin
   null;
end No_Buffer;
```

The select statement above allows the consumer task to accept either Task_A_Event or Task_B_Event, whichever occurs first for each iteration of the loop. The "terminate" option is executed after both Task_A and Task_B have terminated. This terminate option terminates the consumer task.

Using the Ada Rendezvous approach the consumer select clause becomes an event listener for the specified events. As you can see, the task entries become both an event notification and a message passing mechanism. In effect, the message is the event.

An example output of this program is:

```text
Task A message number 1
Task A message number 2
Task B sent the value 100
Task A message number 3
Task B sent the value 101
Task A message number 4
Task B sent the value 102
Task B sent the value 103
Task A message number 5
Task B sent the value 104
Task A message number 6
Task A message number 7
Task B sent the value 105
Task A message number 8
Task B sent the value 106
Task A message number 9
Task B sent the value 107
Task A message number 10
Task B sent the value 108
Task B sent the value 109
Task B sent the value 110
Task B sent the value 111
Task B sent the value 112
Task B sent the value 113
Task B sent the value 114
Task B sent the value 115
```